# Divide select in SQL does not work

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Can you help me please with the divide select in SQL? I use the Oracle Apex Express Edition. I have three tables. In English (original names are in brackets): User (Uzivatel), Event (Udalost) and Groups of users (Skupina_u). Their context is on screens:

Now I have to use divide select in SQL. This select is formulated: You must show all users who were on all events. In my tables, you can see that I have two users, who were on all events. They are part of group “SK2.” I am using this select:

```
select *
from   Uzivatel
where  not exists (select *
                   from   Skupina_u
                   where  not exists (select *
                                      from   Udalost
                                      where  Skupina_u.ID_uz = Uzivatel.ID_uz
                                      and    Skupina_u.ID_uz = Udalost.ID_uz))
```

But the result is: no data found.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Which 2 users are you referring to? Which events did they go? Do you have other tables? Which is the primary key of table Events (`Udalost`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is answering the question you pose in English . . . "Find all users who are on all events."

This is an example of a set-within-sets query.  I think the best approach is using aggregation (because the same structure can be used for many questions).  Let me show you using the English names for the tables and columns:

```
select eu.UserId
from User_Events eu
group by eu.UserId
having count(distinct eu.EventId) = (select count(*) from Events e)
```

That is, select all the users where the number of distinct event ids is the number in the events table.  If you only want events that have users, then use the following `having` clause:

```
having count(distinct eu.EventId) = select count(distinct eventId) from Events e)
```

Comment: @ypercube I think users Martin adn Diana, because thy are in group SK2. This group is asociated with each event. And primary key in table Udalost is ID_ud (on the screen as ID). They go to event to Amsterdam and Bratislava. Table Udalost have two foreign keys ID_o (primary key of Skupina_U) and ID_uz (primary key of table Uzivatel).

Gordon Linoff: Thank you, but I have to use syntax with not exists.

Comment: I updated screen, I added names of tables and names of primary keys.

Comment: This answer suffices, but it is imperative the User_Events.EventId has a foreign key constraint referencing Events.eventId.

Comment: So, I can´t use syntax with not exists in this case...?

Comment: With this select:
select Meno_u
from   Uzivatel
where  not exists (select *
                   from   Skupina_u
                   where Skupina_u.ID_uz = Uzivatel.ID_uz and not exists (select *
                                      from   Udalost
                                      where   Skupina_u.ID_uz = Udalost.ID_uz))

I get all users from table "Uzivatel..." But now I need show only two users who were on all events - Martin and Diana. They are in the group "SK2".

Comment: @Mato . . . You can use `not exists` and various types of joins.  I find the aggregation to be the most general way of approaching these types of problems.